# Running node on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethstaker/comments/13k4hsc/lighthousebeacon_in_raspberry_pi_fails/) problem: I have successfully installed the Ubuntu-Node-Variant on the SD-card, and logged in, but trying to enable the service `lighthouse-beacon` as described in the tutorial on ethereum.org I get

```
Unit lighthouse-beacon.servie not found.
```

Is it, or is it not possible to run a node on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 8 GB of RAM? How to use `geth`  and `nimbus`? Where to place the public IP? I assume the image just does not work at the moment, because it says "currently outdated"  besides the RP on [this site](https://ethereum-on-arm-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)